# php exec('alpr') returns an empty array with openALPR installed

Tags: php, openalpr

I am writing a php script that makes use of openALPR installed on my linux computer.

When I type "alpr --version" in the terminal, I get this output

```
alpr  version: 2.2.4
```

But then when I do this in my php script, I get an empty array result. But any other command works just fine.

Here is my code snippet

```
$command = 'alpr --version ';
$result = array();

exec($command, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running that command from the terminal as a different user.

Find out which user php and/or apache is using, then switch user in the terminal.

Try and run the command again.

If the command isn't found, switch back to yourself and type `which alpr`, which will give you the path.

Then switch back to PHP's user, and ensure the $PATH environment variable includes the folder where the `alpr` executable is found.

Also, make sure that the executable is actually executable by that user/group. If not, you'll need to use `chmod` or `chown` or `chgrp` to give PHP permission.

If you get stuck, leave a comment!